# Date gets modified when importing stuff from database to R

Tags: sql, r, type-conversion

I construct a sql query and use the dbGetQuery command to get data into my R platform. The date field is really important for my later steps. So I import the following fields from the db, and modify the date field to be in the date format. I do some processing in R and write this info in a flat file, which is later imported into the db. The really strange thing is that this seems to be shifting all my days back by 2 days. Eg, if I have date = 02-01-2014, the final date in the table is 01-30-2014. This is happening to all the date values. Any idea what's causing this?

```
      sqlStr = paste( "SELECT " ,

              "QUANTITY = " , QUANTITY , "," ,
              "COST_UNIT = " , COST , "," ,
              "DATEVAR = CAST(" , Txn_date, " AS DATE)," , 
              "Margin " ,
              " FROM " ,
                 MFT ,
               sep="")

     txns = dbGetQuery(conn,sqlStr)

     txns$DATEVAR = as.Date(txns$DATEVAR)
```

I tried just a simple query like selecting the date and the key from multiple tables; this also gives me the same results: date is pushed back by 2 days.

Comment: This is not reproducible. Please give us a working example.

Comment: What database are you using? Are you sure you don't have to escape the CAST parameter in quotes? I'm thinking this has little to do with R and more to do with your particular database engine.

Comment: I have Txn_date variable defined already. The query is correctly constructed; the issue does not lie with that. Right after it fetches the txns dataset - the date field gets modified. The date is set back by 2 days. I'm using MS SQL 2012.